# How to import css inside typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I have global css file where i have defined all colors. I tried to import that value inside typescript but it's don't work. This is my last try:

```
get sideWindowStyle(): any {
    switch (this.windowStyle) {
      case 'classicStyle': {
        return {
          '@import' : 'src/styles-library/colors-variables.scss',
          'background-color': '$primary-lightest-color'
        };
      }
      case 'lightStyle': {
        return {
          'background-color': '#ffffff'
        };
      }
      default: {
        return {
          'background-color': '#f1f9fe'
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

Without import or with it its still didn't working.

Comment: Scss files are transpiled into css and aren't available at runtime. And you can't alter a css file that way anyway.

Comment: did you check my answer  ?

Comment: This is the wrong way of styling your view. You should play with CSS only. TS is not responsible for handling view but logic. Read about ```@host``` in scss.

Answer (score 0):

during build transpile it into css and then link that file in your `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/colors-variables.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

sass variable will compiled during the build ant the will not be accessible in run time so you can use css variables

*style.scss*

```
:root {
  --primary-lightest-color: brown;
}
```

*sideWindowStyle*

```
get sideWindowStyle(): any {
    switch (this.windowStyle) {
      case 'classicStyle': {
        return {
          'background-color': 'var(--primary-lightest-color);'
        };
      }
      case 'lightStyle': {
        return {
          'background-color': '#ffffff'
        };
      }
      default: {
        return {
          'background-color': '#f1f9fe'
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

[**CSS variables MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Answer (score 0):

If window.style is a class in template then you can achieve required style using Host:

```
:host(.classicStyle) { 'background-color': '$primary-lightest-color' }
:host(.lightStyle) { 'background-color': '#ffffff' }
background-color: '#f1f9fe'
```

This piece of code will automatically change your background-color property if either of these two class will be there on the container of your element.

If window.style is a TS object then on the basis of its value, change the host element's class to `classicStyle` or `lightStyle` and then the given `host` code will work.